# Floor tiles gloss - match the Viewport Shading gloss for multiple rotated objects

Tags: armature

I want to use 4 tiles to create a floor 1 for inner and outer corner each, 1 for the edges and a full one for the middle. With the rotations on each tile the gloss also changes with it like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbxB9.jpg.

Applying the Transforms doesn't work and i can't really look for a solution because i don't even know how to really call it other than gloss.

Comment: You can't use tangent space normal maps with position inputs.  They need an actual UV map-- that's where the "tangent" comes from, the direction of increasing U, and it uses that UV map layout to determine which colors mean what on the normal map.  For floor tiles, that are all in world space, pointing at +Z, consider using an object space normal map-- I would expect you could use the same image that you're using.

Comment: Alright now i got it thank you so much!